# Delete element from Broadcast List

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a list of URL, for example:

```
www.google.com
www.yahoo.fr
www.stackoverflow.com
```

I want delete all the URL that contain the String "`oo`" and "`flow`".

I did a python function:

```
def my_function(param1,param2, 
param3,param4,liste_to_delete,liste2_to_delete):
     status=True
     SQL_CONSTANT = "url not like '%"
     URL_SEP = ";"
     # getFirstList
     broadcastListe1String =""
     listtodelete = liste2_to_delete.split(URL_SEP)
     for url in listtodelete:
         broadcastListe1String = SQL_CONSTANT + url + "%'"
         if(listtodelete.index(url) != len(listtodelete) -1):
             broadcastListe1String = broadcastListe1String + " AND "
     my_broadcast = sc.broadcast(broadcastListe1String)
```

Then I did :

```
DataFrame= my_DataFrame.where(my_broadcast.value)
```

This function started from the second element in my list, it do not take 
accound the first element in my list.

How can I change my function do delete also the first element in the list ?
I hope that I was clear
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a `filter` function like this:

```
filter(lambda x: 'oo' not in x and 'flow' not in x, lst)
```

For example:

```
lst = ['www.google.com',
       'www.yahoo.fr',
       'www.stackoverflow.com',
       'www.duckduck.com',
       'www.amazon.com',
      ]

filtered_lst = filter(lambda x: 'oo' not in x and 'flow' not in x, lst)
# filtered_lst = ['www.duckduck.com', 'www.amazon.com']
```

or:

```
lst = ['www.google.com',
       'www.yahoo.fr',
       'www.stackoverflow.com',
       'www.duckduck.com',
       'www.amazon.com',
      ]

ex_words = ['oo', 'flow']

filterd_lst = filter(lambda x: all(w not in x for w in ex_words), lst)
# filtered_lst = ['www.duckduck.com', 'www.amazon.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filter = ['oo', 'flow']
list = ['www.google.com','www.yahoo.fr','www.stackoverflow.com','www.something.com']
for val in list:
    if not any(bad_word in val for bad_word in filter):
        print(val)
```

**Output**

```
www.something.com
```